# How to update setInterval data every x seconds without affecting inside setInterval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

- How can i update **ranType** every 30 seconds.
- since **ranType** is random if ranType === 'works' how to add interval to update inside data every 10 seconds.
- This is what i tried:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  let type = ['works', 'testing'];
  let ranType = type[Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)];

  if (ranType === 'works') {
    setInterval(async () => {
      console.log(`Okay Working ${RANDOM DATA}`);
    }, 10000);
  } else {
    setInterval(async () => {
      console.log(`Testing also working ${RANDOM DATA}`);
    }, 10000); // But RANDOM DATA should update every 10 seconds - I have RANDON data
  }
}, 30000); // ranType should update every 30 seconds
```

- expected output:

> After 30 seconds
> if ranType is 'works'
> it should repeat console with random data every 10 seconds

> Again after 30 seconds it (ranType) should change to testing
> if ranType is 'testing'
> it should repeat console with other random data every 10 seconds

- Other issues is its keep repeting 3-4 times every 10 seconds.

Comment: I don't if this is what you actually want, but you keep creating new intervals at every 30 seconds and those will keep repeating forever. Do you want something like repeat works or testing every 30 seconds but only while on those 30 seconds? Then the cycle repeats.

Comment: each setInterval iteration (outer one), it stacks up another setInterval, if you don't want that you should use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

Comment: but is there any other ways to update ranType after 30 seconds?

Comment: i want ranType to update x seconds so it would be works or testing and if its 'works' i want update random data every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think this is what you want, please let me know if is not the expected result. Every 30 seconds the outer setInterval clears the last intervalId and creates a new one.

```js
    let intervalId;

    setInterval(() => {
      let type = ["works", "testing"];
      let ranType = type[Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)];

      console.log("new cycle of interval of 30 seconds");

      clearInterval(intervalId);

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (ranType === "works") {
          intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
            console.log(`Okay Working`);
          }, 10000);
        } else {
          intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
            console.log(`Testing also working`);
          }, 10000);
        }
      });
    }, 30000);
```

**EDIT**

created a new version which might be clearer

```js
    const setIntervalXTimes = (callback, delay, repetitions) => {
      let count = 0;
      let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
        if (count === repetitions) {
          clearInterval(intervalID);
        } else {
          callback();
        }
        count++;
      }, delay);
    };

    setInterval(() => {
      let type = ["works", "testing"];
      let ranType = type[Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)];

      if (ranType === "works") {
        setIntervalXTimes(() => console.log(`Okay Working`), 1000, 3);
      } else {
        setIntervalXTimes(() => console.log(`Testing also working`), 1000, 3);
      }
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks but your edit doesn't seems to work in my case first version works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const ranType_reset_period = 30000;
const works_reset_period = 10000;
const testing_reset_period = 10000;
const random_data_reset_period = 10000;

let works_interval = -1;
let testing_interval = -1;

let RANDOM_DATA = "RANDOM_DATA_DEFAULT";

function reset_random_data() {
  let sample_random_data = ['RANDOM_DATA_1', 'RANDOM_DATA_2', 'RANDOM_DATA_3', 'RANDOM_DATA_4'];
  RANDOM_DATA = sample_random_data[Math.floor(Math.random() * sample_random_data.length)];
  console.log('RANDOM_DATA', 'RESET', RANDOM_DATA);
}

function get_random_ranType() {
  let type = ['works', 'testing'];
  return type[Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)];
}

function reset_works_interval() {
  console.log(`Okay Working ${RANDOM_DATA}`);
}

function reset_testing_interval() {
  console.log(`Testing also working ${RANDOM_DATA}`);
}

function reset_rantype() {
  clearInterval(works_interval);
  clearInterval(testing_interval);

  if (get_random_ranType() === 'works') {
    works_interval = setInterval(reset_works_interval, works_reset_period);
  } else {
    testing_interval = setInterval(reset_testing_interval, testing_reset_period); // But RANDOM DATA should update every 10 seconds - I have RANDON data
  }
}

setInterval(reset_random_data, random_data_reset_period);
setInterval(reset_rantype, ranType_reset_period);
```

---

### ***Illustration***

```js
const ranType_reset_period = 30000;
const works_reset_period = 10000;
const testing_reset_period = 10000;
const random_data_reset_period = 10000;

let works_interval = -1;
let testing_interval = -1;

let RANDOM_DATA = "RANDOM_DATA_DEFAULT";

function reset_random_data() {
  let sample_random_data = ['RANDOM_DATA_1', 'RANDOM_DATA_2', 'RANDOM_DATA_3', 'RANDOM_DATA_4'];
  RANDOM_DATA = sample_random_data[Math.floor(Math.random() * sample_random_data.length)];
  console.log('RANDOM_DATA', 'RESET', RANDOM_DATA);
}

function get_random_ranType() {
  let type = ['works', 'testing'];
  return type[Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)];
}

function reset_works_interval() {
  console.log(`Okay Working ${RANDOM_DATA}`);
}

function reset_testing_interval() {
  console.log(`Testing also working ${RANDOM_DATA}`);
}

function reset_rantype() {
  clearInterval(works_interval);
  clearInterval(testing_interval);

  if (get_random_ranType() === 'works') {
    works_interval = setInterval(reset_works_interval, works_reset_period);
  } else {
    testing_interval = setInterval(reset_testing_interval, testing_reset_period);
  }
}

setInterval(reset_random_data, random_data_reset_period); // But RANDOM DATA should update every 10 seconds - I have RANDON data
setInterval(reset_rantype, ranType_reset_period);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort seems working :)